# Can this be a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have this game. In a bucket, I have $x$ number of balls, one of them is black. I  randomly pick out balls out of the bucket one at a time (with no replacement). If I pick out a ball that is not black, the game is ongoing, so I move on to the next ball. If I pick out the black ball, the game is finished, so I put all the balls back and start a new game.

The process has two states: ongoing and finished. I can go from ongoing to either ongoing or finished, and from finished to ongoing or finished (by immediately getting a black ball in the new game). However, the probability of going form ongoing to ongoing increases the more times I fail to get the gold ball in one game. Is this still a Markov chain? If not, what is it classified as?

Comment: There is one gold ball and one black ball? Or did you mix the colors?

Comment: Oh, woops. One of them is black. There is no gold.

Answer (score 0):

If you regard as the "states" those two ones (ongoing and finished), then it's certainly a Markov chain, but it's not **stationary** (or not "time-homogeneous"). The probabilities of falling in each state at time $t$ depends only on the previous state *and* the time $t$, but it does not depend on other past states.

The transition matrix, assuming the states $S=({\rm ongoing} , {\rm finished})$ would be

$$  M_t=\pmatrix{1 - \frac{1}{x-t} & \frac{1}{x-t} \\
0 & 1
}$$

assuming we start at time $t=0$  - and that $t<x$

Comment: I see. If it is not stationary, what would it be classified as? Thanks!

Comment: Well, as non-stationary. Or "time-inhomogeneous". Truth to be told, these ones are less studied and used. In your particular case, I doubt that it would be practical/useful to model that as a Markov Chain.

Comment: Will it still be possible to make a transition matrix out of it?

Comment: Of course. But, again, it dependends on the time.